# C program data structure stack calculator

Tags: c

I'm studying about data structure coding.
I built a calculator using a stack.
infix to postfix and result
However, I want to get the result after all completing the input.
And I want to "out" the input with an end.
the last line is example when it debug.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 100
#define MAX_EXPR_SIZE 100

enum {
    lparen = -9,
    rparen,
    plus,
    minus,
    times,
    divide,
    mod,
    eos,
    operand
};

int stack[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
char expr[MAX_EXPR_SIZE], postexpr[MAX_EXPR_SIZE];
int pos = 0;
static int isp[] = { 0, 19, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 0 };
static int icp[] = { 20, 19, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 0 };

void add_stack(int *top, int item) {
    if (*top >= MAX_STACK_SIZE - 1)
        printf("Error: Stack is full\n");
    stack[++*top] = item;
}

int delete_stack(int *top) {
    if (*top == -1)
        printf("Error: Stack is empty\n");
    return stack[(*top)--];
}

int get_token(char *symbol, int *n) {
    *symbol = expr[(*n)++];
    switch (*symbol) {
        case '(': return lparen;
        case ')': return rparen;
        case '+': return plus;
        case '-': return minus;
        case '*': return times;
        case '/': return divide;
        case '%': return mod;
        case 0:
        case '\n': return eos;
        default: return operand;
    }
}

void print_token(int p) {
    switch (p) {
        case plus:
            printf("+");
            postexpr[pos++] = '+';
            break;
        case minus:
            printf("-");
            postexpr[pos++] = '-';
            break;
        case times:
            printf("*");
            postexpr[pos++] = '*';
            break;
        case divide:
            printf("/");
            postexpr[pos++] = '/';
            break;
        case mod:
            printf("%");
            postexpr[pos++] = '%';
            break;
        case eos: 
            printf(" ");
            break;
    }
}

void postfix(void) {
    char symbol;
    int token;
    int n = 0;
    int top = 0;
    stack[0] = eos;
    token = get_token(&symbol, &n);
    for(; token != eos; token = get_token(&symbol, &n)) {
        if (token == operand) {
            printf("%c", symbol);
            postexpr[pos++] = symbol;
        }
        else if (token == rparen) {
            while (stack[top] != lparen)
                print_token(delete_stack(&top));
            delete_stack(&top);
        } else {
            while (isp[stack[top] + 9] >= icp[token + 9])
                print_token(delete_stack(&top));
                add_stack(&top, token);
        }
    }

    while ((token = delete_stack(&top)) != eos)
        print_token(token);
    printf("\n");
}

int eval(void) {
    int token;
    char symbol;
    int op1, op2;
    int n = 0;
    int top = 0;
    stack[0] = eos;
    token = get_token(&symbol, &n);
    for(; token != eos; token = get_token(&symbol, &n)) {
        if (token == operand)
            add_stack(&top, symbol - '0');
        else {
            op2 = delete_stack(&top);
            op1 = delete_stack(&top);
            switch (token) {
                case plus: add_stack(&top, op1 + op2); break;
                case minus: add_stack(&top, op1 - op2); break;
                case times: add_stack(&top, op1 * op2); break;
                case divide: add_stack(&top, op1 / op2); break;
                case mod: add_stack(&top, op1 % op2); break;
            }
        }
    }
    return delete_stack(&top);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Input expression : ");
    scanf("%s", expr);
    printf("Postfix expression: ");
    postfix();

    strcpy(expr, postexpr);
    printf("Evaluation of the expression : %d", eval());
}
```

this is example when it done

```
input //
(8*6)+2/4
(8*6)+4/2
out // 

print//
postfix (8*6)+2/4
result (8*6)+2/4
postfix (8*6)+4/2
result (8*6)+4/2
//
```

Comment: You haven't clearly stated what specific problem or issue you have with the code. What result are you getting with the code? More importantly what debugging have you done and what did you find? Run your program in a debugger and trace it as it runs.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some problems and possible improvements to your code:

- `printf("%")` has undefined behavior. You should write `printf("%%")` or simply `putchar('%')`
- you should parse numbers with multiple digits
- you should skip spaces and TABs
- you should detect invalid characters
- you should detect invalid expressions
- you should not use global variables

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 100

enum {
    error = -10,
    lparen = -9,
    rparen,
    plus,
    minus,
    times,
    divide,
    mod,
    eos,
    operand,  /* 0 and above are operand values */
};

static int const isp[] = {  0, 19, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 0 };

void add_stack(int *stack, int *top, int item) {
    if (*top >= MAX_STACK_SIZE - 1) {
        printf("Error: Stack is full\n");
        return;
    }
    stack[++*top] = item;
}

int delete_stack(int *stack, int *top) {
    if (*top < 0) {
        printf("Error: Stack is empty\n");
        return eos;
    }
    return stack[(*top)--];
}

int get_token(const char *expr, int *pos) {
    for (;;) {
        int c = expr[*pos];
        if (c == '\0' || c == '\n')
            return eos;
        *pos += 1;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t')
            continue;
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            int value = c - '0';
            while ((c = expr[*pos]) >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                *pos += 1;
                value = value * 10 + (c - '0');
            }
            return value;
        }
        switch (c) {
        case '(': return lparen;
        case ')': return rparen;
        case '+': return plus;
        case '-': return minus;
        case '*': return times;
        case '/': return divide;
        case '%': return mod;
        default:  *pos -= 1; return error;
        }
    }
}

void print_token(char *postexpr, int *ppos, int token) {
    int pos = *ppos;
    switch (token) {
    case error:  postexpr[pos++] = '?'; break;
    case lparen: postexpr[pos++] = '('; break;
    case rparen: postexpr[pos++] = ')'; break;
    case plus:   postexpr[pos++] = '+'; break;
    case minus:  postexpr[pos++] = '-'; break;
    case times:  postexpr[pos++] = '*'; break;
    case divide: postexpr[pos++] = '/'; break;
    case mod:    postexpr[pos++] = '%'; break;
    case eos:    break;
    default:
        /* insert a space between numbers */
        if (pos > 0 && postexpr[pos - 1] >= '0' && postexpr[pos - 1] <= '9')
            postexpr[pos++] = ' ';
        pos += sprintf(postexpr + pos, "%d", token);
        break;
    }
    *ppos = pos;
    postexpr[pos] = '\0';
}

int put_error(const char *message, const char *expr, int col) {
    if (col < 0) {
        printf("%s\n", message);
    } else {
        printf("%s at column %d\n", message, col + 1);
        printf("%s\n%*s\n", expr, col + 1, "^");
    }
    return -1;
}

int postfix(const char *expr, char *postexpr) {
    int stack[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    int token, n = 0, top = 0, pos = 0, last = eos;
    stack[0] = eos;
    while ((token = get_token(expr, &n)) != eos) {
        if (token == error) {
            return put_error("syntax error", expr, n);
        }
        if (token >= operand) {
            if (last >= operand) {
                return put_error("missing operator", expr, n - 1);
            }
            print_token(postexpr, &pos, token);
        } else
        if (token == rparen) {
            if (last < operand && last != rparen) {
                return put_error("missing operand", expr, n - 1);
            }
            while (stack[top] != lparen) {
                if (stack[top] == eos) {
                    return put_error("invalid parenthesis", expr, n - 1);
                }
                print_token(postexpr, &pos, delete_stack(stack, &top));
            }
            delete_stack(stack, &top);
        } else {
            if (token == lparen) {
                if (last >= operand || last == rparen) {
                    return put_error("missing operator", expr, n - 1);
                }
            } else {
                if (last < operand && last != rparen) {
                    return put_error("missing operand", expr, n - 1);
                }
                while (isp[stack[top] - lparen] >= isp[token - lparen]) {
                    print_token(postexpr, &pos, delete_stack(stack, &top));
                }
            }
            add_stack(stack, &top, token);
        }
        last = token;
    }
    if (last < operand && last != rparen) {
        return put_error("missing operand", expr, n);
    }
    while ((token = delete_stack(stack, &top)) != eos) {
        if (token == lparen) {
            return put_error("unmatched parenthesis", expr, -1);
        }
        print_token(postexpr, &pos, token);
    }
    return 0;
}

int eval(const char *expr) {
    int stack[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    int token, n = 0, top = 0;
    stack[0] = eos;
    while ((token = get_token(expr, &n)) != eos) {
        if (token >= operand) {
            add_stack(stack, &top, token);
        } else {
            int op2 = delete_stack(stack, &top);
            int op1 = delete_stack(stack, &top);
            switch (token) {
              case plus:   add_stack(stack, &top, op1 + op2); break;
              case minus:  add_stack(stack, &top, op1 - op2); break;
              case times:  add_stack(stack, &top, op1 * op2); break;
              case divide: add_stack(stack, &top, op1 / op2); break;
              case mod:    add_stack(stack, &top, op1 % op2); break;
            }
        }
    }
    return delete_stack(stack, &top);
}

int main() {
    char expr[100], postexpr[200];

    for (;;) {
        printf("Input expression: ");
        if (scanf("%99s", expr) != 1)
            break;
        if (!postfix(expr, postexpr)) {
            printf("Postfix expression: %s\n", postexpr);
            printf("Evaluation of the expression: %d\n", eval(postexpr));
        }
    }
    printf("Done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
Input expression: 1
Postfix expression: 1
Evaluation of the expression: 1
Input expression: 1+
missing operand at column 3
1+
  ^
Input expression: 1+1
Postfix expression: 1 1+
Evaluation of the expression: 2
Input expression: (1+2*3)
Postfix expression: 1 2 3*+
Evaluation of the expression: 7
Input expression: (1+2*3)*(3+4*5/6)
Postfix expression: 1 2 3*+3 4 5*6/+*
Evaluation of the expression: 42
Input expression: Done.
```